# How to zoom a GtkTreeView

Tags: gtk3

I want to zoom a `GtkTreeView`. Initially I thought I simply could use `transform` to do that, but it seems like GTK CSS currently does not support `transform`.
So reading up on the CSS docs, it seems my only chance would be to set `font-size`.

Now naively I tried to set `font-size` to `200%` in `GtkStyleContext`.
All I get then is

```
g_object_set_is_valid_property: object class 'GtkStyleContext' has no property named 'font-size'
```

So how is one supposed to set `font-size` in code?

Answer (score 1):

You can start with this:

```py
css_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
css = b"""treeview.view {font-size: 200%;}"""
css_provider.load_from_data(css)
style_context.add_provider_for_screen(screen, css_provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)
```

But, this will set 200% to all treeviews.
If you want (and you probably do) a custom style class which you can attach to any widget, it should look something like 
`.my_style_class { font-size: 200%; }`
And you add this class to specific widget's StyleContext:

```py
widget.get_style_context().add_class("my_style_class")
```